# Avg write latency spikes for disk more than usual. Need help finding the culprit

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, t-sql, tempdb

We recently had increased in disk write latency reported. Though from our monitoring team it was not confirmed from which drive but doing some dmv query I see `tempdb` around avg 32 ms wait on write. Also over the week `tempdb` usage I mean available free space has come down under 50 GB from 300 GB.

I am suspecting this spike could be from `tempdb`. The environment is a mix of OLTP and warehouse people querying data for large select when looking for real time data in case not available from LS standby.

My question is how can I check what in `tempdb` if it is would have caused this spike?

Also can those select queries also contribute to `tempdb` write latency? These select queries are run on tables over TBs of data and user can have part of queries like order by and group by from what I have seen. But I am not sure how to prove they are contributing to sudden spike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is how can I check what in TempDB if it is would have
> caused this spike?

To analyze what impact those queries have on tempdb you could use [sp_whoisactive](http://whoisactive.com/docs/07_default/) since one of the info it outputs is the use of tempdb:

> - **The most confusing of these columns are those related to tempdb.** Each    of the columns reports a number of 8 KB pages. The
>   [tempdb_allocations] column is collected directly from the
>   tempdb-related DMVs, and indicates how many pages were allocated in
>   tempdb due to temporary tables, LOB types, spools, or other
>   consumers. The [tempdb_current] column is computed by subtracting the
>   deallocated pages information reported by the tempdb DMVs from the
>   number of allocations. Seeing a high number of allocations with a
>   small amount of current pages means that your query may be slamming
>   tempdb, but is not causing it to grow. Seeing a large number of
>   current pages means that your query may be responsible for all of
>   those auto-grows you keep noticing.

Another way to show that you have a tempdb related problem is having [sp_BlitzCache™ Result: TempDB Spills](https://www.brentozar.com/blitzcache/tempdb-spills/). As that page says:

> To find the queries that are causing spills, you have several options
> – you can capture and examine actual execution plans, or you can
> collect exchange spill events through extended events. Paul White
> covers your options in his reply to [What frequency of hash/sort
> spills into tempdb is
> concerning?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/66396/what-frequency-of-hash-sort-spills-into-tempdb-is-concerning)

---

> Also can those select queries also contribute to TempDB write latency
> . These select queries are run on tables over TBs of data and user can
> have part of queries like order by and group by from what I have seen.

Certainly yes. If you check the [tempdb database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/tempdb-database?view=sql-server-ver15) doc, you'll see it stores the following objects:

> - Internal objects that the database engine creates. They include:
>   Work tables to store intermediate results for spools, cursors, sorts,    and temporary large object (LOB) storage.
>    Work files for
>   hash join or    hash aggregate operations.
>    Intermediate sort
>   results for operations    such as creating or rebuilding indexes (if
>   SORT_IN_TEMPDB is    specified), or certain GROUP BY, ORDER BY, or
>   UNION queries.